# Kotlin Collection: indexOfFirst vs find

Tags: kotlin, collections

It might be a stupid question, but I am not sure whether to use indexOfFirst() or find() as both "Returns the first element matching the given [predicate]". The only difference is that one returns -1 and other null. When should I use indexOfFirst() or find(). Is there any advantage of one over other. Consider the following code snippet.

```
private val mPersonList = mutableListOf<Person>()

private fun findPerson(person: Person) {
    val position = mPersonList.indexOfFirst { it.name == person.name }
    if (position != -1) {
        doSomethingWithPerson(mPersonList[position])
    }
}

private fun findPersonWithFind(person: Person) {
    val foundPerson = mPersonList.find { it.name == person.name }
    foundPerson?.let { doSomethingWithPerson(it) }
}

private fun doSomethingWithPerson(foundPerson: Person) {
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: One gives the object found, the other gives the index of the object found. It just depends which piece of information you need. If you are immediately going to retrieve the object using the index, you should probably use `find()` instead for clearer and less verbose code.

Comment: In your particular example I'd use `find`, as you can beautifully chain the calls, e.g. `mPersonList.find { it.name == person.name }?.also { doSomethingWithPerson(it) }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both functions do nearly the same thing: they both locate the first matching item in a list or array (i.e. the first one for which the given predicate returns true).

The differences between them are subtle:

Most obviously, **`indexOfFirst()` gives the *index* of the matching item, while `find()` gives the item itself**.

Obviously, if you have the index, you can easily get the matching item.  (And, if the list is random-access, such as an ArrayList, then that's very efficient — much less so if it's not, such as a LinkedList.)  Whereas if you only have the item, then you can't find its index without calling `find`, `indexOf`, or `indexOfFirst` again!

So if you need to know the index, then only `indexOfFirst()` will do; but if you don't, then `find()` may be marginally simpler.

The code in the question falls into the latter category: `findPerson()` gets the position but uses it only to index into the list.  So that's a little more long-winded, and (if the list isn't random-access) potentially a lot slower, than `findPersonWithFind()`.

Second, as you say, **if no matching item is found, `indexOfFirst()` returns -1, while `find()` returns null.**

Kotlin provides many ways to use nulls safely (such as the safe-call `?.` operator, the elvis `?:` operator, smart-casting, extension functions on nullable receivers, and many helpful functions in the standard library).  But there are no equivalents for dealing with -1, so using `find()` is likely to make it easier to safely handle the not-found case.

By the way, the nullability is made clear in the alternative name for `find()`, which is [`firstOrNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-or-null.html) — though that also has overloads which take no predicate and simply return the very first item in the list if it's not empty.  (The standard library is moving toward `…OrNull()` function names, probably because it makes the nullability very clear, especially when it's a common naming convention.)

So, which one you use depends on your needs.

It's also worth being aware of some related functions.  All of them have equivalents which find the *last* matching item: [`findLast()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/find-last.html)/[`lastOrNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/last-or-null.html), and [`indexOfLast()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of-last.html).

There's also the older [`indexOf()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of.html) function, which checks for (equality with) a given object, instead of using a predicate.  (That, too, returns -1 if not found, which is probably why `indexOfFirst()` and `indexOfLast()` do the same.)  Though if the list is sorted, a [`binarySearch()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/binary-search.html) or [`binarySearchBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/binary-search-by.html) is likely to be a lot faster than a full scan.